# Can't get NextGen gallery in translated post

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I'm creating a custom WordPress theme. So far, it was only in one language, and getting galleries in the code was working fine. That's the code I've been using:

```
// Sometimes this    
echo nggShowGallery( $id ); 

// Sometimes this, as well
echo do_shortcode("[nggallery id='{$id}']");
```

Now, when creating a second language, using Polylang, this code will only get the gallery for the original page or any other page in the former language, but it won't work for any page in any other language. Also, the page stays absolutely blank even though I've set `WP_DEBUG` to `true`.

Googling this issue I've found that there seems to be a lot of trouble using NextGen in multilingual sites.

Any clue?

Comment: Never used Polylang, however I have ngg working on a site with Qtranslate, using NextGEN Query plugin.  You can use echo ngq_gallery('1') in your templates, however it prints the images as is to the page, you'd need to echo them into the format required.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Talknerdytome. May I ask you which version of each plugin are you using?

Comment: NGG 2.0.61 nextgen query 2.1.1 Qtranslate 1.3.0 Just to reiterate, I'm basically using ngg as an uploader, removing all thier scripts and using my own gallery management.  However, I think it would work if  you just left their scripts there and outputted in the required format

Comment: Thank you @Talknerdytome. I've finally moved to WPML as the plugin for translations, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally managed the site to work by making a new WordPress install and using WPML as the plugin for translations. Everything's working fine now. So I guess there was some kind of incompatibility between Polylang and NextGen. Not even installing WPML on the first site solved the issue; I had to begin from scratch.

In case this is useful to someone, I was using NextGen 2.0.65 with Polylang 1.3.1. This didn't work.

Now I'm using NextGen 2.0.66 and WPML 3.1.5. Works fine.